# Является ли слово "действительно" вводным в моем предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Вот фрагмент [справки по Markdown](https://rus.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).

> В конце пятого эпизода выясняется, что
>   >! он, действительно, его отец.

Разве слово "действительно" здесь является вводным?

---

Предположим, что ранее было высказано предположение, что "он его отец". А теперь оно подтвердилось: "Он действительно его отец". Никак не вводное. Другого контекста я не могу предположить.

Comment: ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО, вводное слово

Выражает уверенность говорящего в сообщаемом, употребляется для подтверждения, признания правильности сказанного ранее.

Comment: См.:[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum)

Comment: В вашем примере возможны оба толкования. Если ранее, как вы отметили, говорилось о том, что он его отец, а теперь эта мысль подтвердилась, тогда это вводное.

Comment: @Серж не стоит избегать формы ответов.

Comment: Aer, не хочу повторять уже высказаную вами мысль, тем самым дублируя ответы. Ничего нового я не написал,. лишь потвердил ваш ответ. Поэтому написал в комментарии.

Comment: @Серж думаю, дублирования ответов тут не может быть )

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, я всем поставил плюсы! Вместе вы доказали, что моя претензия к справке необоснована.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Невозможно дать *всю* информацию в комментарии, поэтому предоставляю результаты своего "расследования" — как ответ.
*Хорошую* ссылку дал @Aer, но ***спорную***. Вот она ([**Толковый словарь Ушакова**](http://ushakovdictionary.ru/word.php?wordid=11978)):

*ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО*
1. нареч. На самом деле, в действительности, подлинно. *Его что-то, действительно, грызло и мучило.* Тургенев.
2. в знач. вводного слова. В самом деле, вправду. Это, действительно, так. || Да, точно (разг.). Действительно, вы были правы.

***Полное*** предложение И.С.Тургенева выглядит так:
***Я должен, однако, прибавить, что в последнее время я стал замечать необычное выражение заботы и тревоги на лице Теглева, и не «фатальная» то была меланхолия: его что-то действительно грызло и мучило.***
[**Стук… Стук… Стук!.. часть VI**](https://www.litres.ru/ivan-turgenev/stuk-stuk-stuk/chitat-onlayn/)

Получается, что здесь (в ссылке) сразу несколько ошибок:
1. Цитата оформлена неправильно, т.к. дана только ***часть*** предложения.
2. Если "действительно" ***действительно*** наречие, то запятых в примере не должно быть.
3. ***В полном*** предложении запятых нет.

Итак: "действительно" — хитрое слово. Думаю, что ошибки в справке нет, просто без контекста *однозначного* вывода сделать практически невозможно.
(Посмотрите, КАК изменчив смысл: в целом и в "оторванном" предложениях.)

Answer (score 2):

Толковый под ред. Д. Н. Ушакова:

1. нареч. На самом деле, в действительности, подлинно.
2. в знач. вводного слова. В самом деле, вправду. Это, действительно, так.

В приведенном вами примере трудно определить, что именно имеется в виду — подходят оба толкования, поэтому возможны как вариант с запятой, так и без нее.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61914/discussion-on-answer-by-aer---).

Answer (score 2):

maestro, я пока не не комментирую два других ответа и обсуждения по ним (там пока просто разговоры глухих со слепыми, забыли про конкретный пример).

Давайте так. В вашем примере, скорее всего, ошибка. Но наверняка сказать будет нельзя даже имея контекст. Просто грамматика формально позволяет и то и другое толкование, а смысловые различия тут незначительны. Возможно, вы и не чувствуете этих различий, почему и не видите возможности считать "действительно" вводным словом.

Иногда помогает простой прием. Если сомнительное слово относится к сказуемому или какому-то одному члену предложения, то это скорее всего наречие, не вводное, поскольку вряд ли как-то может передавать просто авторское отношение или предположение.

У нас: *он действительно [есть] отец.*  - и это наиболее естественное понимание. "действительно есть". Обособление, понятно, не требуется.

Если же спорное слово отражает отношение ко всему высказыванию, то с большой долей вероятия это вводное (хотя тоже не наверняка).

Вот вам контекст, умозрительный, но не фантастический.

*Критик Всезнайкин два года назад в статье о сериале "Отцы и Дети" высказывал предположение, что в конце пятого эпизода выяснится, что Василий Иванович - отец Евгения Васильевича. И в конце пятого эпизода выясняется, что он, действительно, его отец.*

Случай тоже не бесспорный, но всё-таки тут куда больше шансов распознать в "действительно" вводное, оно относится к предложению в целом. Его бы, правда, в начало фразы перенести, тогда куда нагляднее будет, но и так сгодится.